# Regex find words only containing two vowels

Tags: r, regex

I need to find words with exactly two vowels using regex and matching

This is what I have:

```
.*[aAeEiIoOuU].*[aAeEiIoOuU]
```

The problem is it is also giving me words with three or more vowels and I only want two. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1

You can use `gregexpr`

```
ss <- c("one", "two", "three", "hundred", "thousand");

ss[lengths(gregexpr("[aeiou]", ss)) == 2];
#[1] "one"     "three"   "hundred"
```

---

### Method 2

Or using `strsplit`:

```
ss <- c("one", "two", "three", "hundred", "thousand");

# Number of vowels
nv <- lapply(sapply(tolower(ss), strsplit, ""), function(x)
    sum(x %in% c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")))
ss[nv == 2];
#[1] "one"     "three"   "hundred"
```

---

Comment: @RichScriven Nice & thanks, I had forgotten about `lengths`. Edited & fixed.

Answer (score 1):

***`find words only containing two vowels`***

Here is a really good way.

`\b[^\WaAeEiIoOuU]*[aAeEiIoOuU][^\WaAeEiIoOuU]*[aAeEiIoOuU][^\WaAeEiIoOuU]*\b`

Explained

```
 \b                        # Boundry start
 [^\WaAeEiIoOuU]*          # Words, not vowels (optional)
 [aAeEiIoOuU]              # Vowel 1 (req'd)
 [^\WaAeEiIoOuU]*          # Words, not vowels (optional)
 [aAeEiIoOuU]              # Vowel 2 (req'd)
 [^\WaAeEiIoOuU]*          # Words, not vowels (optional)
 \b                        # Boundry end
```

Comment: Can confirm: `ss <- c("one", "two", "three", "hundred", "thousand")
ss[grepl("\\b[^\\WaAeEiIoOuU]*[aAeEiIoOuU][^\\WaAeEiIoOuU]*[aAeEiIoOuU][^\\WaAeEiIoOuU]*\\b", ss)]`

Comment: You could avoid the need to repeat the lower and upper cases each time (probably in many ways), but `ss[grepl("\\b[^\\Waeiou]*[aeiou][^\\Waeiou]*[aeiou][^\\Waeiou]*\\b", ss, ign=TRUE)]` is one.

Comment: @thelatemail - Hello! I don't know what you're saying man, is it about the _Ignore Case_ option? A wise man once told me, don't throw bricks in a glass house. While it may look like a shorter regex using this option, it's almost _twice as slow_ compared to what you call _'repeating'_. In regex engines, logic isn't cheap, and ignore case has some logic. Instruction-wise. incrementing the address, doing a primitive `character compare` is as cheap as it gets.

Comment: @thelatemail - Here's a bench for you. `Regex1:   \b[^\Waeiou]*[aeiou][^\Waeiou]*[aeiou][^\Waeiou]*\b
  Options:  < i >
 Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
 Matches found per iteration:   3
 Elapsed Time:    0.80 s,   801.01 ms,   801009 µs
 Matches per sec:   187,263
 -----------
 
 Regex2:   \b[^\WaAeEiIoOuU]*[aAeEiIoOuU][^\WaAeEiIoOuU]*[aAeEiIoOuU][^\WaAeEiIoOuU]*\b
  Options:  < none >
  Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
  Matches found per iteration:   3
  Elapsed Time:    0.56 s,   564.43 ms,   564432 µs
    Matches per sec:   265,753`

Answer (score 1):

You can express it as: "maybe some consonants, then a vowel, then maybe some consonants, then a vowel, then maybe some consonants".

`^[^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$`

So you can do:

```
grepl("^[^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$", s, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

Or, slightly shorter:

```
grepl("^[^aeiou]*([aeiou][^aeiou]*){2}$", s, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

Comment: Can confirm: `ss <- c("one", "two", "three", "hundred", "thousand");
ss[grepl("^[^aAeEiIoOuU]*[aAeEiIoOuU][^aAeEiIoOuU]*[aAeEiIoOuU][^aAeEiIoOuU]*$", ss)]`

Comment: Does R not have a way to do a case-insensitive regex? That's annoying.

Comment: @SteveBennettㄹ - of course it does `grepl("blah", x, ignore.case=TRUE)` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're currently allowing any number of any characters, followed by a vowel, followed by any number of any characters, followed by a vowel. Consider the following:

popopo can be broken down into:

```
[pop] - anything
[o] - a vowel
[p] - anything
[o] - a vowel
```

Hope that helps you figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try package `stringi`. The function `stri_count_regex` can be of help here, i.e.

```
library(stringi)

x <- c('dfgsirys', 'fsggofasef', 'sdfgdgidga')

stri_count_regex(x, '[aAeEiIoOuU]')
#[1] 1 3 2

#or
stri_count_regex(x, '[aAeEiIoOuU]') == 2
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

#or

x[stri_count_regex(x, '[aAeEiIoOuU]') == 2]
#[1] "sdfgdgidga"
```

Answer (score 0):

In base r, with `gregexpr`, you can search for single vowels, and then filter it to strings with exactly two matches:

```
> ss <- c("one", "two", "three", "hundred", "thousand");
> gregexpr("[aeiou]", ss)
[[1]]
[1] 1 3
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1 1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] 3
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

So to find the ones with exactly two vowels, find all that have a length-2 answer, and subset ss to that -

```
> ss[ vapply(gregexpr("[aeiou]", ss), length, 0L) == 2 ]
```